# AngularJs and prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, prerender

I'm working on a Single Page Application developed in AngularJs and using Prerender.io for known SEO issues. In AngularJs I set Prerender.io following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io.).

Except for the home page, all other pages are rendered correctly;
I think the homePage has a timing problem because it has a list that needs to be populated and this could slow it down a lot.

It is sufficient to use the variable `$window.prerenderReady` and ng-cloak or there may be other solutions (AngularJs or Prerender.io settings)
to be applied to solve the problem?
Thank you

Comment: Could you provide the code? Even linking the tutorial you followed we can investigate better knowing exactly what is going on.

Comment: It’s really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when *the question doesn’t include any of the buggy code.*

Comment: Feel free to send us an email at support@prerender.io. We're happy to help make sure your pages are rendering correctly!